# Margin property not working with :root selector

Tags: html, css

I have used the `:root` selector to apply a `margin` to all the elements on the page; while the `color` and `font-family` properties work,the `margin` property doesn't. Am i making a mistake?

I have refered to the following site https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-root-pseudo-class on using the `:root` CSS selector and in the examples it verifies the usage of a `margin` property.

```css
:root {
  margin: 0;
  color: red;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="new">Lorem.</p>
  <p class="title">Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, saepe animi? </p>
  <p class="price">1$</p>
  <button>Buy</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while the `color` and `font-family` properties work,the `margin` property doesn't

`color` and `font-family` are [inherited properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance).

`margin` is **not** an inherited property.

If you want to set the `margin` of **all elements on a page** to `0` (which is probably a bad idea), use the *universal selector `*`*:

```
* { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although i would like to ask why adding a margin of 0 is a bad idea? I am learning by my self and i ask for your advice.

Comment: @Sketchypotatoman - Think about paragraphs printed in a book. There's a vertical space between each paragraph which makes the book easier to read, right? By default, when you use a `<p>` element in your HTML, you'll get that same vertical spacing for free, because `<p>` elements have default margins. When you assign `margin:0` to everything, you lose that "for free" behaviour. Similar applies to a number of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are being applied as intended, it's just that the `body` element defaults to a margin of 8px. The `html` tag is your root element here so it's not being overridden.

Try

```
:root {
  color: red;
  font-family: Arial;
}

:root body { 
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
:root *{
  margin: 0;
  color: red;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Or even simpler

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  color: red;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

"*" selects all elements on the page.
I hope this helps!